# Display axis values inside BarChart bars of MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I want to archive something similar to the following chart:

[image: HorizontalBarChart with embedded into bars labels]

Basically, I want to display labels (let's say all labels of one of the axis) inside bars in `BarChart` or `HorizontalBarChart`, in addition to the values of a bar itself. 
The reason to do this is because, in my case, labels of YAxis are quite long, so it's not enough space to display them outside of the Chart. But inside each bar there is lots of space, guaranteed in my case. So it's quite reasonable to basically name each bar (what does this bar means) right inside it. I haven't found any API to do this (I was looking in v2.1.1).

I need this for `HorizontalBarChart`, so labels would be also horisontal, but vertical labels for `BarChart` would be also great!

Is there a way to do this? Any solutions would be helpful, including some custom additions to the library features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there is not really a feature to do this.
However, there is a little **hack** (or at least I think there is) which you could try.

- Put your `XAxis` to the left side and let the labels be drawn inside of the content area of the chart by calling `chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE)`

In that way the labels should be drawn over the bars. You can further reposition the labels by using the `setXOffset(...)` and `setYOffset(...)` methods of the `XAxis` class.

Comment: Yeap, that trick solved my problem exactly as I wanted. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: But what if one of the bars is too small to hold the label text?

Comment: Well done! I got the job done for me as well. @Zeeshan in that case the text would have a part of it ahead of the bar.